# In RollerCoaster Tycoon 3, do billboards have any negative effects?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

Title just about says it, but I'll clarify anyway.

In RollerCoaster Tycoon 3, billboards provide a small amount of income per billboard. However I've always wondered, do billboards have any negative effects, such as guests not liking the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this website/their wiki http://rct.wikia.com/wiki/The_Complete_Scenery_List

Billboards only count as a standalone scenery object with no status effects to visitors/park attraction